# Find an Equation of the Tangent Line to the Curve at the Given Point: $y=e^{2x}\cos\pi x$, (0,1)

Tags: calculus

$y=e^{2x\ }\cos\pi x$

What are the steps to solving this problem?

I will assume number 1 is to find the derivative since it ask for the tangent.

$e^{2x}\cdot [\cos\pi x]'+(\cos\pi x)\cdot [e^{2x}]'$

$e^{2x}\cdot -\sin\pi x\cdot \pi+(\cos\pi x)\cdot e^{2x}\cdot 2$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Absolutely. Now the tangent is at x = 0, so you will note get the slope. I think you will get it from here.

Comment: Shailesh - I am actually having a problem finding the derivative of the derivative. Can you show me step by step?

Comment: You did find the derivative correctly. Now, why do you need the second derivative for this question ?

Comment: To find the Curve at the Given Point (0.1)

Comment: No, see the answer spelled out nicely below by Chuks.

Comment: Type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x in math mode to produce, respectively, $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your result gives: $$m=dy/dx=2e^{2x}\cos(\pi x)-\pi e^{2x}\sin(\pi x).$$

Substituting $0$ for $x$ gives $$m=2.$$

**Hint:** Use $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$, where $x_0=0,y_0=1$ and $m=2$, and finish up!

Comment: Type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x in math mode to produce, respectively, $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$.